# 32 gigabytes memory card to 8 megabytes

Tags: hardware

while formatting my memory card it has decreased to 8 megabytes.
Originally it is 32 Gigabytes memory card.
any idea on it, how to reformat as 32 gigabytes

Comment: It could be hardware problem and the card has crashed either form some electrical damage or because it is fake. You can test if your card with [H2Test](http://mympx.org/Downloads/p13_sectionid/2/p13_fileid/13)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this? https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/

**From http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=13138**

by **aztecoso08**

> "I had the same problem, only 56MB would show. I used the program from
>   this link. I formatted with the "FULL (overwrite)" option, which took
>   a while, then the full SD card was available to me again. Thanks
>   bredman"

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you are running on the Windows OS.

The raspbian operating system is a port of Debian Wheezy ( a Linux distro) , Linux uses the ext based file systems, which is not read windows as a result you will only see partitions that are either fat or NTFS based.

If you have Linux you can use gparted to detect and format the SD card to a file format of your choice or you can use the link ( https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/ )provided by Arita to format the SD card from windows.

Also you can verify the actual size of the SD card by right clicking my computer -> manage -> disk management. Here you will see your SD card with the actual size and the amount of free space etc.